# Disable automatic pageview tracking with Google Analytics analytics.js (ga)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics.js

I have a need to include the Google Analytics analytics.js `ga()` script on a site but I want to disable the automatic pageview collection. I still want to be able to use the dynamic/virtual pageview tracking (i.e. `ga('send', 'pageview', url);` ) but *only* those requests.

How can I accomplish this?  I've found ways to do it with `gtag()` but I do not utilize gtag and that is not an appropriate solution for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the automatic pageviews that the ga script automatically does, just delete this command:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', url);
```

Then, in Universal Analytics, you can send a virtual pageview by running this code at the moment you want:

```
ga('send', { 'hitType' : 'pageview', 'page' : 'name of virtual pageview' })
```

Comment: But a standard pageview will also be executed at time of load. I want to disable that automatic tracking.

Comment: If you remove the ga('send', 'pageview'); command, no pageviews will be sent automatically

Comment: Remove ga('send', 'pageview'); and use my code when you want to send a pageview... (I don't understand why my answer has a negative vote, probably those who did it not even tried the code...)

Comment: No, this is not what is needed. You are telling me to remove code to track dynamic/virtual pageviews. If you re-read the question I am asking how to remove the automatic pageviews that the ga script automatically does. So your answer does not apply to the question and does not answer it.

Comment: I re-read another time the question, so I thought you understood that to avoid the send pageview you needed to remove the command called... send pageview -->  ga('send', 'pageview', url); Surely you can't track virtual pageview with ga('send', 'pageview', url);. So, probably you need to clarify what you mean with "but only those requests" (only some pages? use an if.. then...else). We are trying to help you, but obviously from your answer it is clear that you already know how to do it.

Comment: If you just add the GA tracking script it will automatically send pageviews. You can in addition use the virtual page view code. My question was to turn off the automatic collection and only send the virtual ones. 

And the code I posted for virtual pageviews came from production code that works so yes, you surely can use that code for virtual pageviews.

Comment: Remove this from the page: ga('send', 'pageview', url);